# Best practices to concat async data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, rxjs

Currently, I'm making three API calls in 3 separate epics and updating specific states with the 3 returned promise objects. After states are updated via redux, I'm trying to concat all 3 arrays together in a certain order and then display them on the page. I believe there's a problem since these are async and data is coming back at different times. My component that renders the data is looking for this combined array but the array is not fully populated before the render happens.

Sometimes the array will have a couple objects and sometimes it' will have 50 when Im searching the same thing. I know what the exact amount of data objects is suppose to be returned. Where should the best place be to concat all the data from when I submit the search query to when the data gets rendered on the page? Right now I'm performing the concat in componentDidMount of the component that is suppose to render the data, but it isn't reliable.

Tried to concat the 3 arrays into one in a separate function and then passing it into the reducer.

Also tried concatting inside componentDidMount and then passing it into the reducer.

Can't show code.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you could probably do is to have a single api endpoint that returns you the three arrays already joined together - basically pushing this logic to the server.  But if that is not feasible...

I think the reason your code is not working the way you want is that `componentDidMount` will only fire once - when the components initially mounts.  As the different calls take different times to come back, you'll only see whatever was loaded when `componentDidMount` happened to fire.

Some possible ideas:

- One approach you could use is to pass the three arrays into your component as props, and concat them in the `render` method.  As each one is populated, your component will re-render itself and keep itself up-to-date.
- Personally I'd consider the concat call to be "data logic" (not "view logic") and thus keeping it out of your react components could be a good idea.  You could consider using something like [Reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) to move the logic more into your redux code.

By default both of these approaches will cause your react component to rerender as each of the ajax calls returns.  If this is a problem for your data sizes, you could then look into [optimisations](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html) to make it faster.